# Добавить элемент jquery

Tags: jquery

Который день ломаю голову, помогите...

```
<div class="left-block">
    <span id="666" class="add_guest">
       <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="center-block"></div>
```

Как при клике по fa-plus добавить в center-block элемент  (id="666" должно так же попасть в value="666")

В итоге должно получится

```
<div class="center-block">
   <input class="text" itype="text" value="666">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.fa-plus').click(function(e) { 
  var value = $(this).closest('.add_guest').attr('id');
  $('.center-block').append(`<input class="text" type="text" value="${value}"/>`);
});
```

Comment: Супер !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', '.fa-plus', function(){
var val = $(this).parent('span').attr('id');
$('.center-block').html('<input class="text" itype="text" value="'+val+'">');
});
```

Comment: Все что было в блоке center-block удаляется...